# Combining 2 Lua Logitech scripts in 1

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Can someone help me combine these two scripts in one. I tried but couldn't make it work. I'm not very good at this...
I want to use them on Logitech scripting for a game and I wanna make them work together.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    while (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsModifierPressed(fast_loot_key) and fastloot) do
        Sleep(10)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(10)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(10)            
        if not IsModifierPressed(fast_loot_key) then
            break
        end
    end
end
```

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
                Sleep(1)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end             
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      if IsModifierPressed(fast_loot_key) and fastloot then
         repeat
            Sleep(10)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(10)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
            Sleep(10)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(10)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
            Sleep(10)         
         until not IsModifierPressed(fast_loot_key)
      elseif IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
            Sleep(1)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works great! You are the best.